# Определить есть ли баланс скобок? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Условие задачи: 
Задана строка,содержащая круглые,квадратные и фигурные скобки.Определить есть ли баланс скобок?
Код с комментариями(объяснениями) пожалуйста.

Comment: Добавте в вопрос ваше решение.

Answer (score -1):

Не Python. Своего рода псевдокод. За правильность не ручаюсь. Самому интересно, будет ли такой подход работать. Задачка-то интересная.

```
// типы скобок: 0 - `(` (круглая), 1 - `[` (квадратная), 2 - `{` (фигурная)

// устанавливаем переменную pos, которая отражает позицию найденной открывающей скобки. Изначально - 0, потому что до сих пор открывающих скобок мы не находили.
pos = 0
// устанавливаем переменную n, которая нужна для подсчета вложенных скобок. Грубо говоря, уровень вложенности, на котором находимся. Изначально - 0.
n = 0
// m - количество открывающих скобок в строке. Посчитайте любым способом. Регулярные выражения, циклы, функции - не важно. Важно, чтобы переменная m равнялась количеству открывающих скобок в строке.
m = countOpens()

цикл (пока i < длины строки)
    если ("первая" скобка уже была найдена (то есть flag = true))
        если (символ - открывающая скобка любого типа)
            если (i = длина строки - 1)
                // если при этом проверяем последний символ строки, значит закрывающей скобки уже не найдем.
                баланс не соблюдается. Выбрасываем ислючение, выводим результат в консоль - что угодно.
            n = n + 1
        иначе если (символ - закрывающая скобка любого типа)
            n = n - 1

            если (n = -1)
                если (тип найденной закрывающей скобки = type)
                    // следующий заход в цикл начнем с позиции предыдущей открывающей скобки + 1
                    i = pos + 1
                    // группа "закрылась", поэтому увеличиваем переменную g на 1
                    g = g + 1
                    // устанавливаем flag в `false`, чтобы при следующем заходе в цикл программа явно поняла, что она теперь имеет дело с новой группой скобок.
                    flag = false

                    если (g = m)
                        // если группы правильно закрылись столько раз, сколько было открывающих скобок в строке, значит больше входить в цикл нет смысла
                        возвращаем положительный результат и выходим из цикла.
                    иначе
                        // какая-нибудь конструкция вроде `continue` в JavaScript или `next` в Ruby, которая явно начинает новую итерацию цикла
                        continue
                иначе
                    баланс не соблюдается. Выбрасываем ислючение, выводим результат в консоль - что угодно.
        иначе
            если (i = длина строки - 1)
                // если при этом проверяем последний символ строки, значит закрывающей скобки уже не найдем.
                баланс не соблюдается. Выбрасываем ислючение, выводим результат в консоль - что угодно.

    иначе
        // изначальный вход. Открывающая скобка из "группы" еще не была найдена.
        если (символ - открывающая скобка любого типа)
            // нашли первую открывающую скобку из группы.

            если (i = длина строки - 1)
                // если при этом проверяем последний символ строки, значит закрывающей скобки уже не найдем.
                баланс не соблюдается. Выбрасываем ислючение, выводим результат в консоль - что угодно.

            // запоминаем ее тип, позицию в строке и помечаем флагом, что первая открывающая скобка из группы была найдена.
            type = тип открывающей скобки (смотри первый комментарий)
            pos = позиция текущего символа в строке
            flag = true (помечаем флагом, что "первая" открывающая скобка была найдена)
        иначе если (символ - закрывающая скобка любого типа)
            // потому что последовательность не может начинаться с закрывающей скобки. Первой найденной скобкой должна быть открывающая, иначе баланс не соблюдается.
            баланс не соблюдается. Выбрасываем ислючение, выводим результат в консоль - что угодно.

    i = i + 1
```

---

### Примеры

1. `)` - баланс нарушен.

   Изначально `pos` и `n` равны `0`.

   Входим в цикл. `i` равно `0`.

   Первая скобка еще не найдена. Поэтому выполнится условие `иначе` в строке 32.

   Символ - закрывающая скобка. Поэтому выполнится условие `иначе если` в строке 45. Программа завершается.
2. `(` - баланс нарушен.

   Изначально `pos` и `n` равны `0`.

   Входим в цикл. `i` равно `0`.

   Первая скобка еще не найдена. Поэтому выполнится условие `иначе` в строке 32.

   Символ - открывающая скобка. Поэтому выполнится условие `если` в строке 34.

   Управление передается в строку 37. Проверка `если` в этой строке выполняется, поскольку `i` = 0 и `длина строки - 1` тоже равна 0. Программа завершается.
3. `(())` - баланс соблюдается.

   Изначально `pos` и `n` равны `0`.

   Входим в цикл. `i` равно `0`.

   Первая скобка еще не найдена. Поэтому выполнится условие `иначе` в строке 32.

   Символ - открывающая скобка. Поэтому выполнится условие `если` в строке 34.

   Условие в строке 37 не выполняется.

   Устанавливаем переменные: `type = 0` (скобка круглая), `pos = i` (то есть `pos = 0`), `flag = true`.

   Увеличиваем `i` на 1.

   Входим в цикл. `i` равно `1`.

   Первая скобка уже найдена (`flag = true`). Поэтому выполнится условие `если` в строке 8.

   Условие в строке 9 выполняется.

   Условие в строке 10 не выполняется.

   Увеличиваем `n` на 1. Теперь `n` равно 1.

   Увеличиваем `i` на 1.

   Входим в цикл. `i` равно `2`.

   Первая скобка уже найдена (`flag = true`). Поэтому выполнится условие `если` в строке 8.

   Условие `если` в строке 9 не выполняется.

   Выполняется условие `иначе если` в строке 14, потому что скобка закрывающая.

   Уменьшаем `n` на 1. Теперь `n` = 0.

   Условие в строке 17 не выполняется.

   Увеличиваем `i` на 1.

   Входим в цикл. `i` равно `3`.

   Первая скобка уже найдена (`flag = true`). Поэтому выполнится условие `если` в строке 8.

   Условие `если` в строке 9 не выполняется.

   Выполняется условие `иначе если` в строке 14, потому что скобка закрывающая.

   Уменьшаем `n` на 1. Теперь `n` = -1.

   Выполняется условие в строке 17.

   Выполняется условие в строке 18.

   `i = pos + 1` (то есть `i = 1`), `flag = false`, `g = g + 1` (то есть `g = 1`)

   Условие в строке 26 не выполняется, но выполняется условие в строке 29.

   Входим в цикл. При этом `i` уже равно 1.

   Первая скобка еще не найдена. Поэтому выполнится условие `иначе` в строке 32.

   Символ - открывающая скобка. Поэтому выполнится условие `если` в строке 34.

   Условие в строке 37 не выполняется.

   Устанавливаем переменные: `type = 0` (скобка круглая), `pos = i` (то есть `pos = 0`), `flag = true`.

   Увеличиваем `i` на 1.

   Входим в цикл. `i` равно `2`.

   Первая скобка уже найдена (`flag = true`). Поэтому выполнится условие `если` в строке 8.

   Условие `если` в строке 9 не выполняется.

   Выполняется условие `иначе если` в строке 14, потому что скобка закрывающая.

   Уменьшаем `n` на 1. Теперь `n` = -1.

   Выполнится условие в строке 17.

   Выполняется условие в строке 18.

   `i = pos + 1` (то есть `i = 1`), `flag = false`, `g = g + 1` (то есть `g = 2`)

   Условие в строке 26 выполняется. Баланс соблюдается. Программа завершается.

---

На самом деле примеры довольно банальны, но вы сами видите, что со всего 2 группами скобок приходится расписывать такие длинные алгоритмы. Честно, не знаю, будет ли такой подход работать на самом деле. Но, надеюсь, кто-нибудь рискнет проверить :)

Answer (score -1):

```
def is_balance(st, bstart='([{', bend=')]}'):
    '''balanced=True, unbalanced=False'''
    dt = dict.fromkeys(range(len(bend)), 0)
    for s in st:
        if s in bstart:
            dt[bstart.index(s)] += 1
        elif s in bend:
            i = bend.index(s)
            dt[i] -= 1
            if dt[i] < 0:
                return
    return not any(dt.values())

a = is_balance('есть ли [баланс] скобок? (Python)')  # balanced
b = is_balance('есть ли [баланс скобок? (Python)')  # unbalanced
c = is_balance(')(')  # unbalanced
print(a, b, c)
```

Comment: `is_balance(')(')` возвращает `True`. Не уверен, что это ожидаемое автором поведение